# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [.

Tags: c#, php, json, http, json.net

I'm doing C# JSON <-> PHP JSON for the first time.
Thought I'd get on an easy road but seems like I've hit the rock.

I'm fairly sure that JSON from Newtonsoft allows "**[**" character but not sure why i have this error instead?

Here's my C# code:

```
public class SystemJSON
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ResponseData { get; set; }
}

public static class SystemCall
{
    public static String Post(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
    {
        byte[] response = null;
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            response = wc.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
        }
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
    }
}

string system_Response = SystemCall.Post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/edsa-NEFS%20(PHP)/api.php", new NameValueCollection()
{
    {"do_work",  Functions.Get_Department_List.ToString()},
    {"api_data", null }
});

**SystemJSON systemJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SystemJSON>(system_Response);** //<-- Error happens here.

if(systemJSON.Status == true)
{
    //do stuff here
}else
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, systemJSON.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

And here's my PHP code:

```
<?php

// Load Request
$function_name = isset($_POST['do_work']) ? $_POST['do_work'] : '';
$api_data = isset($_POST['api_data']) ? $_POST['api_data'] : '';

// Validate Request
if (empty($function_name)) 
{
    SystemResponse(false, 'Invalid Request');
}
if (!function_exists($function_name)) 
{
    SystemResponse(false, 'API Method Not Implemented');
}

// Call API Method
call_user_func($function_name, $api_data);



/* Helper Function */

function SystemResponse($responseStatus, $responseMessage, $responseData = '')
{
    exit(json_encode(array(
        'Status' => $responseStatus,
        'Message' => $responseMessage,
        'ResponseData' => $responseData
    )));
}



/* API Methods */

function Get_Department_List($api_data)
{
    //Test ------------------------------------------START
    $node = array();
    $dept = array();
    $responseData = array();


    $dept['id'] = 1;
    $dept['name'] = "General";
    $dept['description'] = "Forms, Samples, Templates, Catalogs, etc";
    $dept['status'] = 1;
    array_push($node, $dept);

    $dept['id'] = 2;
    $dept['name'] = "Test";
    $dept['description'] = "Testing";
    $dept['status'] = 1;
    array_push($node, $dept);


    $responseData["dept"] = $dept;

    SystemResponse(true, 'SUCCESS', $responseData);
    //Test ------------------------------------------END

}

?>
```

And here's my error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path
>   'ResponseData', line 1, position 51.

Comment: Please update your question to include the **exact** value (don't guess) of `system_Response`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your C# SystemJSON class does not match the structure of the incoming JSON correctly.

`ResponseData` in your C# SystemJSON class is listed as a `string` but your PHP appears to be pushing out a complex object inside that property. You can't deserialise an object into a string - there is no way for the deserialiser to know how to translate the object structure into a suitable string, and anyway it's not generally a useful or logical thing to do. So instead it throws an error to say the object structure doesn't match.

The specific error you're seeing means the deserialiser is expecting a `"` to denote the start of a string but instead it's seeing `{` denoting the start of another object.

---

Why is this happening? Well, your PHP code will produce a JSON response which looks like this:

```
{
    "Status": true,
    "Message": "SUCCESS",
    "ResponseData": {
        "dept": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Test",
            "description": "Testing",
            "status": 1
        }
    }
}
```

[Live demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cac94659885747302ea6012a7e1b714f91d766d7)

As you can see, ResponseData contains an object, which has a "dept" which in turn is another object with four more properties.

To deserialise this properly, your SystemJSON class will need to be altered, and you'll also need two sub-classes to help it out:

```
public class SystemJSON
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public ResponseData ResponseData { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseData {
    public Department dept {get; set; }
}

public class Department {
    public string id {get; set; }
    public string description {get; set; }
    public int status {get; set; }
}
```

You will now be able to deserialise the JSON correctly. Here is a [live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MHqtJO) of the deserialisation.

---

P.S the `[` character appears to be irrelevant here...it's unclear why you referred to that in your question.

---

P.P.S. From looking at your PHP I'm guessing that you may be intending to return different data structures in ResponseData depending on which parameter was specified for `do_work` - i.e. depending on which PHP function is called. If so then you'll need to amend your C# accordingly so that it deserialises to a different concrete class depending on which API method it requests. Or you could possibly cheat and specify `ResponseData` as `dynamic`, which will then accept any data structure it received, albeit with the caveat that it's now effectively loosely-typed and so you lose certain benefits when compiling the code such as checking for valid usage of property names, data types etc.

Comment: Hmm... okay. i think i understand what you mean. As for the "[", well it was throwing this character when i was testing on another set of dummy string, it was about "[" but then later on i tested different data to be transfered and it show "{" instead. Nvm that, now that you've explained to me, i think i know where went wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ZeroKhor no problem...if you feel the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick next to the answer so it turns green) - thanks :-)